# Why getElementById is not working with php echo when creating a dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a table, and in each row there will be a picture, and when the picture is clicked a js function gets executed, each entry of a row in the table will create a js script for the picture of that row. And for that reason I'm using `<?php echo ?>` on the id of the image and on the getElementById in the script. And I have no problem using the echo on the id of the image, but if I put it inside getElementById the js code doesn't get executed. And if I write instead directly the number of the id let's say
`getElementById("3")` instead of `getElementById("<?php echo $contact['id']; ?>")` it works perfectly, but if use echo it doesn't, even when the source code of the loaded page shows that `getElementById("<?php echo $contact['id']; ?>")` successfully got printed as `getElementById("3")`

Here's the full table's code:

```
             <table>
                   <thead>
                        <tr>
                             <th>#</th>
                             <th>Name</th>
                             <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                   </thead>

                   <tbody>
                        <?php $contacts = getContacts();

                              if($contacts->num_rows) {

                                  foreach($contacts as $contact) { ?>
                                  <tr>
<td>
<img id="<?php echo $contact['id']; ?>" src="img/arrow.png" onclick='removeImage("");'>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function removeImage() {
       document.getElementById("<?php echo $contact['id']; ?>").style.display = "none";
   }
</script>
</td>
                                       <td><?php echo $contact['Name']; ?></td>
                                       <td><?php echo $contact['Status']; ?></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <?php }} ?>

                   </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: You're creating the same `removeImage()` function over and over and over and ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looping, you are recreating the same function over and over again, but with a different ID in each. However, you can't create the same function over and over again with the same name.

On your img change `removeImage('')` to `removeImage(this)`

```
<img id="<?php echo $contact['id']; ?>" src="img/arrow.png" onclick='removeImage(this);'>
```

Then outside of the loop just have a single function that refers to the element passed to it

```
   function removeImage(el) {
       el.style.display = "none";
   }
```